# Error in citing more than two subequations in IEEEtrantools with \cref

Tags: cleveref, subequations, ieeetrantools

I want to get "(4c)-(4e)" instead on produced wrong "(4a)" in the last line. I also got error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% for adjustting large optimization problems
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
%
% for reference ...
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{\textendash}
\crefname{equation}{}{}

\begin{document}
We have the following equations:
\begin{align}
    &1 =   1 \label{eq:Ymin}\\
    & 2 =   2 \label{eq:Omax} \\
    & 3 =   3 \label{eq:Vmin}
\end{align}

\begin{subequations}\label{OptDet}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{s,l}
&\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{1}{l}{x\label{OptDet:Obj}
}\\
s.t. & t = 1,\dots,T\nonumber\\
    & 1 =   1 \label{OptDet:ConstQ} \\
    & 1 \leq 1 \IEEEyesnumber \label{OptDet:ConstYmin}\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminA} \\
&1 \leq 1\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminB} \\
&1 \geq 1\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminC} \\
&1 \geq 1\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminD} \\
    &2 \geq 2 \IEEEyesnumber \label{OptDet:ConstOmax}\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxA} \\
&2 \geq 2 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxB} \\
&2 \leq 2 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxC} \\
&2 \leq 2 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxD} \\
    &3 \leq 3 \IEEEyesnumber \label{OptDet:ConstVmin}\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminA} \\
&3 \leq 3 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminB} \\
&3 \geq 3 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminC} \\
&3 \geq 3 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminD} 
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{subequations}

We have three sets of constraints \cref{OptDet:ConstYmin,OptDet:ConstOmax,OptDet:ConstVmin}, respectively, corresponding to the three equations \cref{eq:Ymin,eq:Omax,eq:Vmin}. 
\end{document}
```

I want to definitely use `IEEEtrantools` in the `article` class and also use `cleveref` for referencing.

Comment: It seems that `cleverref` makes some assumptions about IEEEtrantools that might not be correct anymore. At least I get an error citing `\if@IEEElastlinewassubequation` and searching all files in my TexLive 2023 installation, only `cleverref` refers to it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with using two labels. But you should not ignore compilation errors, and when you get an error you do not understand, please cite it in your question.

Comment: I would avoid cleveref here. it clearly doesn't support properly IEEEtrantools and while it is easy to avoid the error message, repairing the problem with the 4a would need real digging into the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What is your proper substitution for `cleverref` in this case?

Comment: I would check zref or zref-clever, but I don't know if they will work with IEEE which does lots of special numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular example works (almost) out of the box with `zref-clever`, in case you'd like to try it out. The only adjustment needed is to set currentcounter inside `IEEEeqnarray` because of how `amsmath`'s `subequation` handles counters.

However, @UlrikeFischer is right in saying that `zref-clever` provides no special support for `IEEEtrans`. This should normally not be a problem, but since, as she says, it does lots of special numbering, it may be a problem. Truth is, I'm not acquainted with `IEEEtrans`, and haven't checked it to work well with `zref-clever`. So, if you choose to use it, beware of possible edge cases.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\AddToHook{env/IEEEeqnarray/begin}{%
  \zcsetup{ currentcounter = equation }%
}
\zcRefTypeSetup{equation}{
  rangesep=\textendash,
  name-sg=,
  name-pl=,
  Name-sg=,
  Name-pl=,
}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% for adjustting large optimization problems
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
We have the following equations:
\begin{align}
    &1 =   1 \label{eq:Ymin}\\
    & 2 =   2 \label{eq:Omax} \\
    & 3 =   3 \label{eq:Vmin}
\end{align}

\begin{subequations}\label{OptDet}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{s,l}
&\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{1}{l}{x\label{OptDet:Obj}
}\\
s.t. & t = 1,\dots,T\nonumber\\
    & 1 =   1 \label{OptDet:ConstQ} \\
    & 1 \leq 1 \IEEEyesnumber \label{OptDet:ConstYmin}\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminA} \\
&1 \leq 1\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminB} \\
&1 \geq 1\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminC} \\
&1 \geq 1\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstYminD} \\
    &2 \geq 2 \IEEEyesnumber \label{OptDet:ConstOmax}\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxA} \\
&2 \geq 2 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxB} \\
&2 \leq 2 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxC} \\
&2 \leq 2 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstOmaxD} \\
    &3 \leq 3 \IEEEyesnumber \label{OptDet:ConstVmin}\IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminA} \\
&3 \leq 3 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminB} \\
&3 \geq 3 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminC} \\
&3 \geq 3 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{OptDet:ConstVminD}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{subequations}

We have three sets of constraints \zcref{OptDet:ConstYmin,OptDet:ConstOmax,OptDet:ConstVmin}, respectively, corresponding to the three equations \zcref{eq:Ymin,eq:Omax,eq:Vmin}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for solving the issue. Only how can change the output format of `zref-clever` (similar to what I did by `\crefname{equation}{}{}`) to not produce the additional `equation` before the number?

Comment: @alb Ah, I had missed that detail, included now. But in your actual document, you may have to do some more similar adjustments. And it's not a "solution to the issue", just rather an alternative.

Comment: After multiple times of running I am getting "We have three sets of constraints ??, ?? and ??, respectively, corresponding to the three equations (1)–(3)."! and three of these warnings: `Reference OptDet:ConstYmin on page 1 undefined on input line 48`

Comment: I'm using overleaf PdfLaTeX compiler with TeX Live version 2022

Comment: @alb Until very recently, `zref-clever` had special treatment for labels inside `amsmath` math enviroments, and the same is not done for `IEEEtrans`. With the latest kernel and the new `label` hook, that's no longer needed, and should work out of the box. Can you get TeX Live 2023 with Overleaf now? (And even then, I'm not sure of the standing of their current packages, these changes are not even a couple of months old...).

Comment: TeX Live 2023 is not exist in the Overleaf (at least in my account)!

Comment: Can I just import a file (`.sty`) to my project to run its latest version?

Comment: @alb I'm not an Overleaf user and I'm also not really acquainted with their updating policies. I also don't know the standing of the current set of packages you can get in Overleaf. `zref-clever` should work in most cases, though `IEEEtrans` appears to need special treatment, which is not available, before the new label hook was introduced. And no, if you can't get the current `zref-clever` to work by just copying the `.sty` because it needs the latest LaTeX kernel and, if you had it, you'd also have the latest `zref-clever`, in which case you wouldn't need to manually copy anything.

Comment: @alb Another thing you can try is to use `\zlabel` instead of `\label` inside `IEEEeqnarray`. `amsmath` math environments need `\label` because they are typeset twice and only `\label` is supported. But I don't know if `IEEEtrans` environments have the same treatment. Try it out, it may work (or it may not).

Comment: Thanks, yes, changing `\label` to `\zlabel` just within `IEEEeqnarray` (and not `align` environment) results required results without error.

Comment: @alb Great to hear that!  :)